# Error while installing libgnomecanvas in MacOS Ventura (Frama-C pre-requisite) using brew on terminal

Tags: macos, homebrew, frama-c

I am trying to install Frama-C in MacOS Ventura, which has as pre-requisite the installation of libgnomecanvas, but I get an error when installing by using *brew*.

When I use

```
brew install libgnomecanvas
```

I obtain the following error:

> Error: libgnomecanvas has been disabled because it has an archived
> upstream repository!

and the installation finishes there.

Is there anywork around for this?

Comment: As Virgile said, you can ignore those outdated instructions and just run `opam install frama-c` (if it still asks for lignomecanvas, you may need to run `opam update` and then `opam install frama-c`; if it *still* does not work, then you have an old OCaml version and need to do something like `opam switch create 4.14.1` to get a newer OCaml, and then you should be able to install a recent Frama-C without the GTK-based GUI. Then you can install and run Ivette, the new GUI, which *does* work on macOS. The instructions do to so are displayed by opam after installing the `frama-c` package.

Comment: Also, please consider adding the Frama-C version to your question, since the phrase "which has as pre-requisite the installation of libgnomecanvas" is only true for *some* versions of Frama-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libgnomecanvas` is needed for the GUI, when compiled against `gtk2`, a very old version which is more and more difficult to find on actual systems. Normally, you can also compile it against `gtk3`, without `libgnomecanvas`. However, according to [this comment](https://git.frama-c.com/pub/frama-c/-/issues/2648#note_208210), there are issues with this version as well on macOS. You can still compile the command-line version, though. Basically, `opam install frama-c` should work, as the `opam` [package](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/frama-c/) disables the `gtk` dependencies when on macOS. The [installation instructions](https://git.frama-c.com/pub/frama-c/blob/master/INSTALL.md#installing-frama-c-on-macos) of Frama-C should probably be updated, though.

Answer (score 0):

My mac is M1 MacbookPro, ventura 13.1.
I've installed `opam install frama-c.25.0` before, and in the folder of opam I couldn't find frama-c-gui.
I've tried the method above from @Virgile, but it didn't work out for me.
After comparing the packages I've installed with one of my colleague who have succeeded in installing frama-c and his mac is M2, I installed one of the different packages and I succeed in opening the frama-c-gui!
Below are what I've installed with opam:
`opam install lablgtk`.
[result for the installing lablgtk command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lurVp.png).
After this, I could use frama-c-gui and frama-c-gui appeared in the opam bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation installing an old version of `frama-c` on my mac. My case is:

- frama-c version to install: v24.0 - Chromium
- my device: Mac mini M1, 2020 with Ventura 13.0.1

The installation `opam install "frama-c=24.0"` will fail complaining about `libgnomecanvas` as the op showed, the workaround is do the following before that:

```bash
opam depext --install -y lablgtk3 lablgtk3-sourceview3
opam depext --install -y frama-c
```

The idea is from [frama-c chromium - 24.0 installation doc](https://frama-c.com/html/installations/chromium.html) under the **Installing opam and Frama-C on WSL** section.

Then the `frama-c 24.0` can be installed, the GUI cannot be used though.